# Matty mouse and Barry the bear

Tags: pattern

Matty, the math mouse, had fun playing Mastermind in the Cool™ Club, but he has worked up a hankering for some honey. So our adventurous arithmetist ventured to the local bee hive. Only to find it missing!

Startled, he looked around and saw a trail of dirt mixed drippings leading to a big cave. At the cave, there was a befuddled looking bear. Matty tried to sneak in but the bear noticed him.

"Hello little mouse, are you trying to steal my hard earned honey?", Barry  the bear scowled. 
"Mayhaps," muttered Matty, the math mouse, meekly. 
"Oh, I am willing to share if you ask... and help me." 
"Okay," Matty mumbled, looking at the heap of honeyed honeycomb. 
"Burt, my bully brother, keeps teasin' me cause I can't figure out his puzzle."
"Do tell."
"Well he likes to yell sentences at me and laughs at me when I can find any pattern."
"Can I hear some examples?"

> "YES GRACE CAN YOU GO", he said but when I asked "NO GRACE CAN'T GO", he laughed and said that didn't fit.
> "ZOO CANOE MOO", he said. Then he said that "RHINO CANOE TOO?" did not work.
> "MARS MOON VENUS SUN" fit but "PLUTO" didn't.
> He said, "CAVERNOUS SUPERNOVA UNCOVERS UNSAVORY SUPREMACY" after which I just gave up and said "NO". And then he said "Ha! You finally found one that works."

So can you figure out what the pattern is?

> **Works:**
>
> "YES GRACE CAN YOU GO",
>
> "ZOO CANOE MOO",
>
> "MARS MOON VENUS SUN",
>
> "CAVERNOUS SUPERNOVA UNCOVERS UNSAVORY SUPREMACY",
>
> "NO"
>
> "MUMMY"
>
> "MUSE SONG"
>
> "A MAGE RUSE"
>
> **Does not work:**
>
> "NO GRACE CAN'T GO",
>
> "RHINO CANOE TOO?",
>
> "PLUTO"
>
> "HI SORRY"
>
> "KNOW"
>
> "BARELY BARRY"
>
> "ZOO KAYAK MOO"
>
> "MUSICIAN'S PIECE"
>
> "A WIZARD'S TRICK"

Hint:

> If there is anything I did with this puzzle that strikes you as peculiar mayhaps you could undo it.

Comment: do we need to calculate? assign numbers to letters in some way?

Comment: Matty the math mouse is not especially equipped for this puzzle.

Comment: I have made some extensive edits to make the puzzle more grammatically accurate. If my edits have somehow misrepresented your intentions, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: day-3, still searching for the solution ...

Comment: @Therandomguy Don't worry, I'm pretty sire you will find it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going with this: a sentence works if

> writing it out in lower case, there are no letters with [ascenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)) (like l, t, h, k).

There's one little thing that still bothers me though, and it's

> "musician's piece", which doesn't technically have any ascenders, but I guess that an apostrophe is still something above the mean line.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Aioros who almost solved the puzzle. Here is the solution :

> Every sentence that is 1 high when it is written in lower-case, excluding letters with descenders.

### Old answer

Certainly not the answer, but my solution seems to work :

> Every sentence that doesn't contain a T works.

Comment: But this answer doesn'**t** work according to Burt!

Comment: Please stop laughing at me Burt :'(

Comment: "HI SORRY" doesn't work, but it should according to your solution.

Comment: That is very newly added, woops, definitely an oversight by me there...

Comment: New try. Thanks to @Aioros who did the most difficult part

Comment: @Aioros Ah not sure who give credit too... Also I do not know the formal definition of an ascender, I was just thinking letters that take up the upper area, so i and j I would have counted.